modify google map polyline app like uber Flutter
I am working on an application similar to Uber, I encounter a problem when I am on a trip and the line is drawn between the car and the destination as shown in the picture.

When the car moves, I draw the line again, but this causes the line to disappear and the new line to appear.
So I did a search and got a code that deletes only the part that I moved and it works well, but sometimes this code does not work and thus the car moves and the line does not talk and is drawn from the starting point to the ending point and the car moves over it.
    Future<void> _getRoute(LatLng from, LatLng to) async {
    String? url;
    url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${from.latitude},${from.longitude}&destination=${to.latitude},${to.longitude}&key=${Consts.googleApiKey}';
    debugPrint("_getRoute $url");
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      debugPrint('===== routes found ====== ${data['routes']}');
      distanceTimeModel = distance.distanceModelFromJson(json.encode(data));
      GoogleMapController googleMapController =
          await mapCompleterController.future;
      googleMapController.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
          LatLng(from.latitude, from.longitude),
        ),
      );
      // Check if there are any routes
      if (distanceTimeModel?.routes != null &&
          distanceTimeModel!.routes!.isNotEmpty) {
        // final String encodedPolyline = data['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'];
        // travelTime = data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text'];
        if (distanceTimeModel?.routes?[0].legs != null &&
            distanceTimeModel!.routes![0].legs!.isNotEmpty) {
          if (distanceTimeModel!.routes![0].legs![0].distance != null) {
            distanceUnit = Utils.formatDistance(distanceTimeModel!
                .routes![0]
                .legs![0]
                .distance!
                .value! /*data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']*/);
          }
          if (distanceTimeModel!.routes![0].legs![0].duration != null) {
            travelTime = distanceTimeModel!.routes![0].legs![0].duration!.text!;
          }
        }

        final List<LatLng> points = Utils.decodePolyline(
            distanceTimeModel!.routes![0].overviewPolyline!.points!);

        if (polyLines.any((polyline) => polyline.polylineId == polylineId)) {
          polyLines
              .removeWhere((polyline) => polyline.polylineId == polylineId);
        }
        polyLines.add(
          Polyline(
            polylineId: polylineId,
            points: points,
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
            // Custom color with transparency
            width: 7,
            // Increase width for a more prominent route
            //   patterns: const [PatternItem.dot],  // Optional: Add a dotted pattern
            jointType: JointType.round,
            // Smooth out line joints
            endCap: Cap.roundCap,
            // Rounded cap for the polyline's ends
            startCap: Cap.roundCap,
          ),
        );

        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        debugPrint('No routes found');
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load directions');
    }
  }

This is the code responsible for deleting the part that the car moved. I got it from ChatGpt
    List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String encoded) {
    List<LatLng> poly = [];
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length;
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
      int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
      do {
        b = encoded.codeUnitAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lat += dlat;

      shift = 0;
      result = 0;
      do {
        b = encoded.codeUnitAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lng += dlng;

      poly.add(LatLng(lat / 1E5, lng / 1E5));
    }

    return poly;
  }

Are there other ways or ideas to solve this problem?

i think its related to state management
